# entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I know this question is being asked several times, but I guess currently, I am little frustrated with this entire signing concept, which tends to be so tedious than even coding and sometimes hilarious how Apple have really messed it up in different versions. When I try to build the distribution ipa file from XCode 4.2, the ipa builds fine and can be installed successfully, however in XCode 4.3.2, the app never gets installed but gives me the error: Jun

: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Now, I am trying to build it through xcodebuild using my mobile.provision and everything seams to look fine until ipa is being generated. However, when installing the app through itunes, this is the error that keeps getting generated. After surfing through blogs/google_search/etc it seams there might be some issue with entitlements which I have no clue how to go and fix this or what might be an issue there anyways?

I hope someone can direct me to the right direction regarding a fix for this.

Thanks

Comment: do you *know* that you need to use entitlements at all?  are you doing  something with iCloud, for example? is this an *Ad Hoc* app, a normal App Store app, or a jailbreak app?

Comment: Nate, I was having couple of problems but now it is fixed. One of them was not being signed with the correct provision, and then had to set "False" get_allow_access parameter I believe in dist.plist file.

Comment: Ok.  If you solved your problem, please describe your solution, and mark the question as solved.  Yes, you can answer your own question :).  That way, other people know not to keep reading your question, thinking that you still need an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The way I solved my problem was first, I was not signing the build with proper provisioning. You can indicate the path of the mobileprovision, or if its being added then simply you can goto XCode Organizer and select the correct provision, right click and show the provision in the finder. If you reflect the names in Organizer and in finder are totally different, and I am not sure why apple tends to keep it like that but that's where one error occurred. After that when I tried compiling and installing the ipa on the device, I encountered another error as "entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile" as  it is not a group member. After going through different blogs and searches it seamed like in Apple's technical note it indicated that if you are building your app for distribution the parameter in dist.plist file "get-task-allow" should be set to as FALSE. Although it indicates that in XCode 4.2, since entitlements is being taken care for you, the type of compilation you choose should reflect to that as well, but apparently that didn't reflected to FALSE. So after switching that to false, the ipa finally got installed to the device. Again, this is for enterprise distribution purpose, so hope in future this may help someone and save some hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem for iOS10 enterprise deployment by removing my app extensions from my app, they were being code-signed differently to the app and was causing this issue.